# Unity AR Vuforia - Start animation if triggerd

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, augmented-reality, vuforia

Hiho Community,

I use Vuforia for my AR-Android-App and I have a object with an animation and I try that it only plays the animation if the object is triggered. No errors but it doesn´t work. Here my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

    public class start_animation_if_trigger : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
    {
            private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

        Animator m_Animator;

        void Start()
            {
            m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
                if (mTrackableBehaviour)
                {
                    mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
                }
            }

            public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                            TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                            TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
            {
                if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                    newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                    newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
                {
                // Play audio when target is found
                m_Animator.Play("C4D Animation Take");
                }
                else
                {
                // Stop audio when target is lost
                m_Animator.Play("none");
                }
            }
    }
```

and some project screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach the script to the imageTarget and then get the animator component of the child object (drag and drop it from the scene or hierarchy panel into the script variable in the inspector).

```
public GameObject gameObjectToAnimate;
private Animator objectAnimator;

....

void Start () {
    objectAnimator = gameObjectToAnimate.GetComponent<Animator>();
    ...
    // 2s pause after instantiate the object
    Invoke("StartAnimation", 2);
}

void StartAnimation() {
    if (objectAnimator != null)
    {
        objectAnimator.PlayInFixedTime("C4D Animation Take");
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: code not tested.

Comment: thx i have a other project now but i defnitly trying it out soon